# jquery ui tabs load event does not fire

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

I have got the following very simple code:

```
function init() {
    var articleTabs = $('#articleTabs');
    articleTabs.tabs('add',
            admin.pageVars.siteRoot + '/articles/themes/' + admin.pageVars.params.id, 'Temas');
    articleTabs.tabs({
        load : function(event, ui) {
            $('.jsonForm').jsonForm();
        }
    });
}
```

This successfully adds a new tab panel to an existing tab control. However upon activation, the load function does never fire.

What is my mistake? (There are no javascript exceptions)

Comment: Did u try running it in firefox and looked at Firebug, if it notifies anything?

Comment: Well, you should construct the tab element and then use the add method. Not backwards.

Comment: the tab is visibly working at the time this code runs.

firebug says everything is fine: it executes the second .tabs({...}), but upon loading the remote page into the control, the load closure isn't executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead, since you're not doing it at the time of the tabs creation:

```
function init() {
  var articleTabs = $('#articleTabs');
  articleTabs.bind('tabsload', function() {
    $('.jsonForm').jsonForm();
  });
  articleTabs.tabs('add', admin.pageVars.siteRoot + '/articles/themes/' + admin.pageVars.params.id, 'Temas');
}
```

This places it first to be safe, but this binds to the [`tabsload` event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#event-load) instead of the `load` option/handler, which isn't set after initial widget creation.

Comment: Sorry, but Im no expert. Should I place the function above at the top of my uiTabs.js file, PLease could you give more details Thanks

Comment: @Rifki - You'd place this in your own file, calling `init();` when you wanted to bind up and create the tabs, or just running the code in the function above as part of a large function, removing the `function init() { }` wrap.

Comment: This solution still doesn't work for me.... see my code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071878/jquery-ui-tabs-load-tabsload-event-does-not-fire